# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input [}

Tags: javascript, php, json

> Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected end of JSON input

[image]

help why I am getting such error

```
 $('.view-profile').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var str = $(this).data('citizens');
    var citizensArray = JSON.parse(str);
    alert(citizensArray[0].id);
});
```

html & php

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm view-profile" data- 
     citizens="<?php echo json_encode($citizens);?>" data-id="<?php echo 
     $citizen['id'];?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-o"></i> Profile</button>
```

Comment: can you  copy the value of `str` ?

Comment: JSON in str in not in correct format, copy it's value to some online JSON parser to find error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the `data-citizens` in single quotes i.e. `data-citizen='<?php echo json_encode($citizens);?>'` as existence of `"` is JSON string will abruptly terminate the attribute value.

And, You don't need to use `JSON.parse()` with [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/), if the data is valid JSON format the method will return JavaScript object.

> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then `jQuery.parseJSON` is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. If the value isn't parseable as a JavaScript value, it is left as a string.

Using `JSON.parse()` with valid JSON result if above error.

So just use

```
var citizensArray = str;
```

```js
$('.view-profile').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var str = $(this).data('citizens');
  console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm view-profile" data-citizens='{ "id" : 1}'> Profile</button>
```

Comment: $citizens is an array or a model citizen so should i wrap it with '{' or '[' ?

this is the unexpected stuff  [{ in the console

Comment: @KarlJucutan, Your code is correct and use `data-citizen='<?php echo json_encode($citizens);?>'`  I made a error in answer corrected now

Comment: thankyou so did try to wrap it in '{' but i noticed that the json format has double '{' wrap then you comment again and i just change the double quote to single one, thanks bro it works :) @Satpal

Answer (score 1):

Before you add JSON into HTML attribute, make sure you encode it.

```
data-citizens="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($citizens));?>"
```

Comment: with `htmlspecialchars`. Check out Satpal's answer for more information